# show length of video file in nsstring with format MM:SS

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

I use below code to get the length of the file and show it in `NSStirng`:

```
float seconds=0.0;
AVURLAsset *asset = [[AVURLAsset alloc] initWithURL:videoURL options:nil];
 if (asset){
        seconds = CMTimeGetSeconds(asset.duration);
    }

    NSString *lengthString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.f:%0.f",seconds / 60, fmod(seconds, 60.0)];

    NSLog(@"Duration: %@", lengthString);
```

The result is:

```
1:1
```

Is there any options in `stringWithFormat` that let us to wirte 01 numbers with 0 before them if the number is less than 10?

In better word, how we can have output 01 when number is 1 or output 09 when number is 9. Also when number is 10 the output is 10 too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `%02d`, converting the `float` to `int` during formatting.  This will be slighly quicker as well.

```
NSString *lengthString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d:%02d", (int)seconds / 60, (int)seconds % 60];
```

Answer (score 1):

Put **%02f** . For example

```
 NSString * lengthString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02f:%02f",seconds / 60, fmod(seconds, 60.0)];
```

Comment: Thanks for help, I accepted @l00phone answer because he posted sooner. but very thanks to you too.